# How can i get the values of the field in Firebase cloud function node

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notifications to a specific device using the Firebase cloud function in nodejs. I successfully get the token that I store inside the firestore.

[image]

As in this screenshot, the `name` field and `record` field are in the same path. The problem is, I want to get the `name`'s value and send it through the notification. Is there is possible way?

This is my NodeJS code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// get the token of the device
async function getToken()  {
    var instance = await admin.firestore().collection('fcm').doc('token').get();
    let _token = instance.data()['token'];
    console.log(_token);

    return _token;
    }


// Send notification when new record are created.
exports.timeInNotification = functions.firestore.document('employee/{employeeId}/record/{recordId}').onCreate(async (event) => {

    // get the fcm token
    var token = await getToken();

    // get the name (the name field is on the same path with the record field)
    var name;

    let body = name + "has time in";
    
    // time in message
    let timeIn = "Time in";
    
    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: timeIn,
            body: body
        }        
    };

    // send the notification
    let response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,message);
    console.log(response);
});

// Send notification when the field inside record update.
exports.timeOutNotification = functions.firestore.document('employee/{employee}/record/{recordId}').onUpdate(async (event) => { 

    // get the fcm token
    var token = await getToken();
    
    // get the name (the name field is on the same path with the record field)
    var name;

    let body = name + " has time out";

    // time out message
    let timeOut = "Time out";

    // notification message
    var message = {
        notification: { 
            title: timeOut,
            body: body
        }
    }

    // send the notification message
    let response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,message);
    console.log(response);
});
```

I tried to get it like the way i get the fcm token here. But there is a several employees that I would not know what employee will create a new documents or update the documents.

Comment: How about adding an employee's FCM device tokens directly into their own node?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.. Do you mean to add the fcm token directly to the node code, without going through the firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ID Token from firebase you can not use it to send notification.
You need to create a FCM Token for each device and put it in the database and use that token to send notification.

here is the difference between them :

-Firebase Authentication ID tokens identify a user. This means that if the same user is signed in on two different devices, they have ID tokens that identify the same user.

-FCM tokens (also called Instance ID tokens) identify an application installation. If you have two tokens from two different devices, there is nothing that is shared between those tokens.